# How to access oauthIdToken returned from Firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to get the `oauthIdToken` of the result fetched from signing with `firebase` using [signInWithCredential](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin). I get the following back upon a successful login:

```
user Object {
  "additionalUserInfo": bg {
    "isNewUser": false,
    "profile": Object {
      "at_hash": "aWhmsdfeef32388EYD8YA",
      "aud": "100423452193-gvmasfasdfasdfasfda7ee0.apps.googleusercontent.com",
      "azp": "100406623293-gvmt0erkkob6asdfadfi7ee0.apps.googleusercontent.com",
      "email": "fake@gmail.com",
      "email_verified": true,
      "exp": 1579142529,
      "family_name": "last name",
      "given_name": "first name",
      "iat": 1579138929,
      "iss": "https://accounts.google.com",
      "locale": "en",
      "name": "first last name",
      "nonce": "Ow_sVcasdf50LdbHdTaro",
      "picture": "https://lsfasfa.googleusercontent.com/-iKnasfasdf34/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/ACHi3re9asdfas7_Erg/s96-c/photo.jpg",
      "sub": "100824234342680931658",
    },
    "providerId": "google.com",
  },
  "credential": Object {
    "oauthAccessToken": "ya29.Il-5B47AOKYEQ5NYikv93gYyyhWu_2FEHEaadfaasfasdfasdfBVJCDXG3HJ9MdqalyyxvZ-6jMoqRsaGzhPUg6Cg862vF25xocHR6rnbh_-HuP2MMey4s59Gx8fXLwgQ99dQ",
    "oauthIdToken": "eyJhbGciOiJSUzsdfagyZDgyMDQwM2VlODUxOGM0YWFiYjJiOWZlMzEwY2FjMTIiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL2FjY291joiZW4iLCJpYXQiOjE1NzkxMzg5MjksImV4cCI6MTU3OTE0MjUyOX0.i-YiWbokasfiP_-xWCHJUyT_aLWp7eb3YCE6mzRUbbuKsdfsdfHptczrMXB5vMZY_5JFp8ZD2zxoNlvhTpuMY3B_zw_5Irk6HzuHGHXyAgzNJjh5n6cYR8gOiOsfsdfcKATpHcG7H_gOCwns_fI44I820qcmrogaEXuW-i3u9X5aXbTYqW5EaZQvQzuHkYHO2VWoktOTZsfsdfsfOaYYGU-tqW-ygAB_aWD7VPjIuUY4ySPF4k6IRR1x3ZysfdsdfdGGarX3isPGxMrDMtbRtsfsdfVaKsZdRtCpbfNUbFO8NR6x-pIvKsdfA",
    "stsTokenManager": Object {
      "accessToken": "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsASDAFASFVmZTJlZDQyOWI3MzY0M2Y2NTEiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.eyJuYW1lIjoicmVudGVyaWkgcmVudGVyaGUuY29tIn19.n7z7HlL9lU7VEOA4fGIHvE9UMLSu5uo1rpfTm6m-N5A8CaKQaDu96sAvsG8iOVx8PYnytadffsafSRHyJoS0bzZbpQS6-YItdM5bIPxLMTFYEb0-Ho-tPnhRBSfWfPqJnK0c18YBFtHTG-0TvLNppmuZFG9AJjZZr0ASIkoOWmkI0gdOUAKBkutwMb3oitxeorT-pUdtKB5Rk23ekewz05oi7R5TI4xpBX5LsPvqaCqI4S5wxHe_BilRiiMhxd_lINdWftEkpctKSApJubML7mB9A",
      "apiKey": "AIzaSysdfsdfsiWO7_2buk",
      "expirationTime": 1579142530341,
      "refreshToken": "AEu4IL01n_G6c4_Wg6fzseXRGPJHEAJnhzw7GLZVTS4RICikJ8PUgmmtNWXjcttOSbmYVCJDzGluUvTNKPHa4aS8gG0R3ijmrvPpcyJFPWZ5dRRDIlzxuoSyt70mewdRYgK4Eao7W21550slj7qHu8ZT_1bACJb31e_y7UnL2QjJEuvKwcWII8v8mgMPpYC2RH6fKg0Xrv9XLBgTxso25KfDrlfHBfYp4t35CzcVqODl71663_xV0WHhQ5gpv1hW0N39MMU5S0UEbQ_FnMmcJUFygaRvHndj2yNVhGwv_Re0uut3hUanPO_bo6OT4VEgIEEZ6cuiq8jzpH_T7d6bwI9eLZNS6IC1Fu8EJFmUWAtsdyBErq0s39gj2uta0uqLIGP_wlP5F_eDiw",
    },
    "tenantId": null,
    "uid": "KlGB4adfadfn9ktr1",
  },
```

Trying to access `oauthIdToken` with `console.log(result.credential.oauthIdToken)` inevitably provides `null` even though the variable is clearly present. I'm assuming this is similar to getting the `accessToken` within `stsTokenManager` where you can only get it using the method `getIdToken()` and `credential.stsTokenManager.accessToken` provides `null`.

How do I access `oauthIdToken`?

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Comment: Please make sure OAuth credentials are redacted when posting them on public forums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took me a day to sort this one out. I was looking at using promises and found the answer by logging the parts of the object.

The output of printing out the result object is very confusing. The issue is that the JSON object representation has keys which don't correspond to the variables on the object. If you use `console.log(JSON.stringify(result.credential))` rather than
`console.log(JSON.stringify(result))` you will see the different variable names.

To see the OAuth Identity Token use `console.log(console.log(result.credential.idToken))` without the oauth prefix. Likewise the access token doesn't have the oauth prefix.

It is important to know that in the Google/Firebase world there are two different types of identity token. The Firebase identity token is obtained from `user.getIdToken()`. It is sent to the server to allow the client to be verified. Its audience in the project identifier. The other type, which is the subject of the question, is the identity token generated by the Auth provider. If the Auth Provider is Google then this is the token you have to use to authenticate against Cloud Functions and Cloud Run services.  The token needs to be sent in a `Authorization: Bearer idtoken` header on the request.